# Excel Date Format Change

Tags: excel, date, format

I receive a CSV file from an external data source with the dates formatted as shown below. I need to "convert" whatever is coming over into a date that can be sorted properly. I've tried text to columns, formulas, importing as text, etc but nothing will change this data into a usable format. Each date comes over in one cell. I've had to clean data in the past but the techniques used in the past are not working with this set. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
 Apr 16 2013 12:40PM
 Apr 19 2012  3:49PM
 Apr 30 2012 10:33AM
 Aug 14 2013 10:25AM
 Aug 29 2013  4:21PM
 Dec 28 2012 10:22AM
 May 13 2013  5:02PM
```

Answer (score 1):

There may well be a better way (such as change the output received!) but meanwhile:

Use Text to Columns (Data > Data Tools) with Fixed width and breaks immediately either side of `Apr 16 2013`. For that column, select Date and MDY. Select the time column and replace A with space A, P with space P. Add the two columns together row by row and format to suit.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not following this step: "Select the time column and replace A with space A, P with space P. Add the two columns together row by row and format to suit."

Answer (score 1):

After importing this field as text, you can apply the following formula to it:

```
=(MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&MID(A1,8,4)&" "&TRIM(MID(RIGHT(A1,7),1,5))&" "&RIGHT(A1,2))*1
```

Then format the cell(s) as date/time (Custom format with `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM` or any appropriate format you need).

If you don't want the time, you can use this one:

```
=(MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&MID(A1,8,4))*1
```

Or [pnut's Text-to-Column method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745946/1578604) which works just as well :)

Comment: @pnuts I think that the apparent leading space was input by the one who edited the question, I just had a look at the original version and there are no leading spaces there :)